# TypeError: message.member.roles.some is not a function

Tags: discord.js

```
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix2}red`)){
    if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Red')) return message.channel.send(`You already has that role `)
    let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Red");
    let member = message.member; 
    message.delete(1)
    member.addRole(role).catch(console.error)
        }   
    })
```

What do I need to change? for it to work?

the error is 
 `` if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Red')) return message.channel.send(`You already has that role `)
TypeError: message.member.roles.some is not a function ``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using discord.js v12 and that's why your code won't work.

Try using `message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Red')` instead of `message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Red')`

Comment: try one more time. fixed the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that message.member is undefined, you might want to check if this is done in a guild or not. If it is in a guild it will return the member property, while if it isn't, it won't. What you want to do is check if the message was sent from a guild or not, try the code below:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  // `!` means `non-existent` or `is not`, and if the user sends the message from a guild  
  // this will not be triggered, since we know they are in, rather than not in, but, if
  // it was sent outside of a guild, say a DM, then it will return the command, not trigerring
  // any errors or such.
  if (!message.guild) return;

  // This will not allow this command to be triggered by the bot itself, since it may
  // return a loop.
  if (message.author === client.user) return;

  // If the author of the message is a bot, then return, since bots can be used to spam
  // and this will also spam your bot's API request. Webhooks work the same way.
  // `||` means `or` if you didn't know.
  if (message.author.bot || message.webhookID) return;

  // Checks if the member has the role "ROLE NAME", and if they do, return.
  if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "ROLE NAME")) return;
  // code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i got this problem when i wasnt checking if the array wasn't in a array format which was like this before

```
if (this.user?.roles.some((r) => this.appHasRole.includes(r))) {
  this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
} else {
  this.viewContainerRef.clear();
}
```

then i changed the code to do more checks which is as below

```
if (
  this.user &&
  Array.isArray(this.user.roles) &&
  this.user.roles.some((r) => this.appHasRole.includes(r))
) {
  this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
} else {
  this.viewContainerRef.clear();
}
```

which then worked. try applying more checks before executing the code and it may work!